# Redis Lua script redis.call('get', 'nonexisting') return value

Tags: lua, redis, eval

It seems the following Redis Lua script returns `false` rather than `nil`, which is contradicting to what the document says:

```
> eval "local r = redis.call('get', 'none'); if r==nil then return 42 end" 0
(nil)
> eval "local r = redis.call('get', 'none'); if r==false then return 42 end" 0
(integer) 42
> eval "local r = redis.call('get', 'none'); if not r then return 42 end" 0
(integer) 42
```

the first `eval` failed at the condition `r==nil`, the second `eval` seems to prove that the return value is `false`

It seems using `not r` is the safest option I have at hand, but the documentation [here](https://redis.io/commands/get) says that the `GET` command would return `nil`

Is this something everyone else has observed and relying upon as a fact that the safest Redis Lua script checking for commands returning `nil` is to use `not r`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, dug deeper in the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/eval#conversion-between-lua-and-redis-data-types), Redis `nil` does convert to `false` in Lua scripts:

> Redis to Lua conversion table.
>
> - Redis integer reply -> Lua number
> - Redis bulk reply -> Lua string
> - Redis multi bulk reply -> Lua table    (may have other Redis data types nested)
> - Redis status reply -> Lua    table with a single ok field containing the status
> - Redis error reply    -> Lua table with a single err field containing the error
> - ***Redis Nil bulk reply and Nil multi bulk reply -> Lua false boolean type***

Comment: Hmm... Some sort of nilophobia in Redis?

Comment: Thanks for copying the relevant snippet in the documentation, as I can't find this information in the documentation anymore. Anyone knows where it is now? Would be great to update the link.